# Data comparison without unique key

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are importing data from external source. This data does not have a global key, so we have Varchars, Dates, etc. to match.

The question is: How to make the perfomance of Varchar comparison better? Also, it there any tool that can allow to see match percentage (Like similiarity of rows: 90%)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst not a direct answer to your question, if you're importing data then Integration Services (if you're not already using it) would be a decent choice.  A couple of the transformations included in SSIS allow for 'fuzzy matching' - that is, matching data based on a confidence level of similarity.

Comment: Can you please point me somewhere where I can get simple steps on how to start using SSIS? This looks great!

Comment: Creating a Simple ETL Package:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx - from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167031.aspx

Comment: See Fuzzy Lookup Transformation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137786.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For finding "similar" matches you could use a *sounds like* comparison:

```
WHERE SOUNDEX(some_column) = SOUNDEX(‘some_string’)
```

Comment: Wow, never heard about this function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a tool to compare data?
 http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/